# React Js Calling another function passing the props

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am new to the react js  and redux. Here, I am using the same component for the two different places and passing some functions as a props.

This is my common component in which I have the following component whose name is TestComp and which is accepting some props one is the function handleChange.

```
<SelectFileButton
    accept='application/pdf'
    handleSubmit={file => handleSubmit(file, 'test')}
/>
```

Now, this component has the implementation of the handleChanges method. Now,
from another place I am using the same component.

```
<TestDocument
    handleSubmit={file => actionFunction(URL,file)}
/>
```

Now this component has it's own implementation of the handleSubmit function. That is in the same component.

Now, what i am trying is while passing the props to the function I am calling the another function in it which will not break the implementation for another component as well.

So, what I tried is passing another function as a props.

```
const actionFunction = (URL,file) => {
    this.handleSubmit()
}

<TestDocument
    handleSubmit={file => actionFunction(URL,file)}
/>
```

So, is there anything that I can do to use this?

Answer (score 0):

If I understood right. You need try this

```
export default function TestDocument (props) {
  return (
    <form handleSubmit={file => props.handleSubmit(URL,file)}>
       ...
    </form>
  );
}
```

Render TestDocument:

```
 <TestDocument handleSubmit={this.handleSubmit}/>
```